# Storing SseEmitter Object in "Redis" database in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, server-sent-events

I couldn't find how to store SseEmitter objects in Spring boot. I looked at the topics opened before, but there is no one giving detailed information about this subject.

I tried converting SseEmitter objects to byte[] form and storing them, but it doesn't work.